# Why does using Ansible variables in Kubernetes secret JSON definition fails?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

Why does using Ansible variable make the following Ansible simple task to fail?

```
- name: Create secret
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      metadata:
        name: somename
        namespace: default
      type: Opaque
      stringData:
        management.json: |
          {
            "Proto": "udp",
            "URI": "stun:coturn.{{ domain_name }}:3478",   <<<=== **HERE**
          }
```

Replacing `{{ domain_name }}` with any string manually like `mydomain` works just fine!

I am not sure what is wrong when using Ansible variable and how can I solve it?

Here is the error I get when running the playbook:

```
    "msg": "Failed to create object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"Secret in version \\\\\"v1\\\\\" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.stringData of type string\",\"reason\":\"BadRequest\",\"code\":400}\\n'",
    "reason": "Bad Request"
```

And as said, removing the variable from the definition works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess you're getting bitten by the ansible+jinja2 auto-coercion behavior due to the leading `{` in that field. The usual work-around for that is one of two ways, depending on whether the upstream system tolerates any leading whitespace or not

#### `|string` filter

```yaml
      stringData:
        management.json: >-
         {{
          {
            "Proto": "udp",
            "URI": "stun:coturn."+ domain_name +":3478",
          } | tojson | string
         }}
```

#### leading whitespace

```yaml
      stringData:
        management.json: |
          {{" "}}{
            "Proto": "udp",
            "URI": "stun:coturn.{{ domain_name }}:3478",   <<<=== **HERE**
          }
```

One can see the erroneous behavior in a simple test

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: |
        foo is {{ foo }} of type {{ foo | type_debug }}
    vars:
      foo: |
        {
          "Proto": "udp",
          "URI": "coturn.{{ inventory_hostname }}:3478"
        }
```

which as written emits

```
    "msg": "foo is {'Proto': 'udp', 'URI': 'coturn.localhost:3478'} of type dict\n"
```

but with the same `{{" "}}` patch applied emits

```
    "msg": "foo is  {\n  \"Proto\": \"udp\",\n  \"URI\": \"coturn.localhost:3478\"\n}\n of type str\n"
```

and similar, although (of course) without the leading space using the `|json|string` pipeline

```
    "msg": "foo is {\"Proto\": \"udp\", \"URI\": \"coturn.localhost:3478\"}\n of type str\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems to be working now with the `white space` version! But I still do not grasp why the version with the escaping character for the `"` and with `\n` character is correct? Maybe this is a basic JSON formatting question, but I don't understand why the correct versions are correct and why the wrong is wrong? Could you explain that in the answer please?

Comment: I don't have a handy way to reproduce your error in order to provide more insight into what, exactly, went wrong with your question but my strong suspicion is that every time something in ansible touched that json-looking string, it _also_ coerced it in some way. I also don't know why `|string` seems to stop that process, but it's been my experience, and for sure the leading whitespace stops it because then `value[0]` is no longer `{` and ansible stops trying to "help" the user

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found, in addition to the suggestions of @mdaniel, is using Ansible **[Template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html)**.

Ansible seems to handle template files (.j2) properly without the need to any workaround. In addition, in my case, I had a relatively large file (in the question I only showed a minimal part), and it makes sense to store it in a template rather that putting it in the task / playbook directly.

Example:

```
- name: Create secret
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    template: secret.yaml.j2
```

Where the `secret.yaml.j2` file exists in a role inside the templates folder and includes this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: somename
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
stringData:
  management.json: |
    {
      "Proto": "udp",
      "URI": "stun:coturn.{{ domain_name }}:3478",
    }
```